# add code to display sku in front of error message

Tags: error

This is the code we are using to display some message.

```
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist', $attributeCode);
```

I want to display SKU in front of this code. I want to add following code :

```
$sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSku();
```

I am trying this :

```
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSku();, 'Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist',$attributeCode);
```

but i am getting syntax error....

please help me to display the code properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('%s - Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist', $_product->getSku(), $attributeCode);
```

If you really need to load the product you can do this.

```
$sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSku();
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('%s - Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist', $sku, $attributeCode);
```